# My createNewNode function does not work once it is called outside of the loop. What could be the problem?

Tags: c

I am having trouble understanding why the createNewNode function does not work again after being called in the for loop. It works fine when I first want to create the new nodes of the linked lists. However, after I call it again in the switch function, the program just crashes. I would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 20


struct Student
{
   char first[SIZE];
   char last[SIZE];
   float score;
   char zip[SIZE];
};

struct node
{
   struct Student records;
   struct node * next;
};

typedef struct node node_t;

//making a global head so it can be accessed everywhere
node_t * head;

//function prototypes
node_t * createNewNode();
node_t * newHead(node_t ** head, node_t * add);
void printList(node_t * head);
void printMenu();
void insertAfterNode(node_t * nodeAfter, node_t * newNode);
void insert(int n);

int main()
{
    int numRec,i,userChoice=9;
    head = NULL;
    node_t * temp;

    printf("Please indicate number of records you want to enter (min 5): ");
    scanf("%d",&numRec);
    getchar();
    printf("Please input records in FirstName LastName Score Zipcode format.\n");

      for(i = 0; i < numRec; i++)
      {
         printf("Please input records in for student #%d: ",i+1);
         temp = createNewNode();
         newHead(&head,temp);
      }




    while(userChoice != 0)
    {
       printMenu();
       scanf("%d",&userChoice);

       switch(userChoice)
      {
      case 1:
         printList(head);
         break;

      case 2:
         numRec++;
         insert(numRec);
         break;
      case 3:

         break;
      case 4:

         break;
      case 5:
         break;
      case 6:

         break;
      case 7:

         break;
      }


    }


    return 0;
}

node_t * createNewNode()
{

   node_t * result = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
   char input[50];
   char temp[20];
   int i;


   fgets(input,50,stdin);
      //assigning the values
   strcpy(result->records.first, strtok(input , " "));
   strcpy(result->records.last, strtok(NULL, " "));
   strcpy(temp, strtok(NULL, " "));
   strcpy(result->records.zip, strtok(NULL, " "));

   result->records.score = atof(temp);
   result->next = NULL;

   return result;


}
node_t * newHead(node_t ** head, node_t * add)
{
   add->next = *head;
   *head = add;
   return add;
}

void printList(node_t * head)
{
   node_t * temp = head;
   while(temp != NULL)
   {
      printf("First Name: %s, Last Name: %s,Score: %0.1f,Zip code: %s\n",temp->records.last,temp->records.first,temp->records.score,temp->records.zip);
      temp = temp->next;
   }
}

void printMenu()
{
   printf("Print records (press 1)\nAdd a new record (press 2)\nDelete record(s) (press 3)\nSearch by zip code (press 4)\nSearch by score range (press 5)\nFind median score (press 7)\nExit the program (press 0)");
}

void insertAfterNode(node_t * nodeAfter, node_t * newNode)
{
   //order is important!
   newNode->next = nodeAfter->next;
   nodeAfter->next = newNode;
}
void insert(int n)
{
   node_t * temp1 = createNewNode();



   node_t * temp2 = head;
   for(int i = 1; i < n-1;i++)
   {
      temp2 = temp2->next;
   }
   insertAfterNode(temp2,temp1);

}
```

Comment: If you think the code for `insert` isn't important to this analysis, think again. `newHead` may be as well, but `insert` is critical, and I'm almost as curious as to what (you think) it does as I am why you didn't include it. Post a [mcve] please.

Comment: Also show us the definition of `node_t`.

Comment: Just made an edit to my original post. I didnt post it all, because I got a warning saying that there was too much code.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you, duh, obviously I'm not having a good night.

Comment: There are a *lot* of things that should be addressed, but right now the biggest is your lack of checking various result codes. When pulling the `userChoice` using formatted input, you leave a cr/lf in the input stream. This (and only this) is what is read by the `fgets` in `createNewNode`. You then march into assuming `strtok` finds the tokens you're looking for (which it doesn't), and `strcpy` from null pointers, which invokes *undefined behavior*. The moral is, *always* know what is going on in your IO, and *always* honor [Spencer's Commandment #6](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html).

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you! I added getchar() after my scanf and I was able to add more nodes to my linked list. Do you have any other things you recommend me do?